# Algorithm to split people into groups with most diversity per group

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, grouping

I'd like an algorithm to put people into groups for an upcoming conference. There's lots of people going, from different regions, departments, genders etc, and they want to split people up as much as possible so get diversity in each group.

So is there either a well known algorithm or even tool in (say) Excel or something to solve this problem, which must be very common?

To simplify the problem say there are
n people (say 100) 
To be split into g groups (say 6) and there should be as close to even number in each group.

They have regions: London, North, Midlands, West, Scotland (mostly London)

Gender: Female, Male, Other

Departments: Sales, Support, Management

Grade: 6 different grades

Additional info 
There are differing proportions of people in each category, i.e. more sales than management.

There probably is a priority in the ordering, they want an even gender split more than an even department split.

I work in C# but happy to read in anything.

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: You may want to lookup "PACKING PROBLEMS".  The Romans tried to solve this problem 2000 years ago and wan't very successful.  Mathematicians are still trying to solve these problems.  The Romans going to war attempted to load their chariots efficiently with minimum number of chariots.  So putting too much in one chariot would slow it down or tip it over.  So the Roman's like you wanted to evenly distribute items.

Comment: A simple approach to code is just to choose a number of random orderings (which should cluster around being balanced) and then pick whichever is best according to your chosen criteria.  You can also try swapping people between groups to see if any swap improves the score.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mjwills
I think that he's asking for an algorithm, not to fix a piece of code, so what could you expect him to have shown? He can't start writing code till he know's the algorithm.

Comment: He could, for example, have some code that populated a list of `People` objects with sample data. _Ultimately this question will likely be closed if no code is included._  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin may be of interest @YairHalberstadt .

Comment: fair enough. It should really be on software engineering I guess

Comment: Examples are always good. Of course one could propose answers, but it is to be expected to see better answers from his perspective if there would be some example. There are some informal things here, e.g. regions -> discrete-names vs. coordinates and some distance-metric. Written like that, you won't get happy treating those as discrete ones. Also classic-stuff like: l1 vs. l2 loss on group-sizes? Or some other metric? Better to decide on that, but sometimes an example helps too.

Comment: Another way to treat this problem would be to represent the data as a graph with verices - people and weighted edges with weight W(i,i) = the number of differences between person i and person j. If only gender is different then W(i, j) = 1, if gender and region are different then W(i,j) = 2 etc. And apply a graph partitioning algorithm like this one: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~harry/pdf/bpartition.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Lets first define a utility function. We want one that's accurate but quick to calculate, so how about how close the proportion of people of each category is in a group compared to the actual proportion of each category in total.

so if a group of 8 has 5 males, 3 males , 4 salespeople and 4 support, but there is an equal split of males and females in total, and 2/3rds the total number of people are sales, the other 1/3rd support the utility function will be
-((5/8-1/2)+(3/8-1/2)+(4/8-2/3)+(4/8-1/3))

The reason there is a minus in front is so that the utility function increases with diversity.

Once you've defined a utility function, there's a lot of ways to go about it, including simulated annealing for example. However for your purposes I recommend hill climbing with random restart, as I think it will be sufficient.

Randomly assign people to different groups, then calculate the utility function. Randomly select one person from 1 group and another from another group, and if the utility will be higher when you swap them do so. Continue swapping, for a number of rounds (eg,200), and then record the assignment and the utility function. Restart from a new random assignment, and repeat the whole process a few more times. Pick the one with the highest utility function.

If that's not clear, ask me to clarify.

Comment: That's a good start i think, but the size of your groups is an invariant based on your neighborhood-definition (swap between 2 groups). Sizes will never change. This might be bypassed by random-restarts, but one could think about other neighboorhoods too (e.g. between 3 groups).

Comment: He says there should be a roughly even number in each group, and I think that it will be easy enough to find a good solution without changing that.

Comment: But *roughly* is a non-constant and depending on the function to optimize, the optimization-value can change a lot when taking this into account.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a trivial problem by any means, and hard, if not impossible to solve with an exact algorithm. I don't know an academic analogue, but this is a perfect use case for stochastic/probabilistic optimization.

You need a fitness function that can convey how diverse the current assignment is with a single number, e.g. something simple and intuitive like:

```
sum
  for each group
    for each trait
      trait_weight * abs(%_occurrence_in_group - %_occurrence_in_population)
```

(in the above case, lower is better)

Choose a method like simulated annealing or a genetic algorithm, and search for an extremum.

Comment: I think hill climbing is far simpler then genetic algorithms or simulated annealing, and for a problem like this with dense solutions should be perfectly sufficient (with random restart).

Comment: Well, SA is very simple (in my opinion). But he did not say anything about the neighborhood which is a core-ingedredient / needed.

Comment: not all that simple if you're programming it yourself, and it's your first experience with artificial intelligence tbh

Comment: It's just one probability-calculation and one random-sampling fed into some if (compared with your alg).