# What software algorithm will select a diverse subset of items from a large set

Tags: algorithm, subset, knapsack-problem

**Setup**

Suppose I have a very large number of items. Each item has a shape, size and colour. They may be

- triangles, circles or squares
- red, green or blue
- small or large

I can't make any assumptions about the distribution of these attributes among the items. I'm *reasonably* sure that it's not one million large, red triangles but that's always a possibility.

**Problem**

I want to pick 36 of my shapes with as "diverse" as possible representation across all attribute classes. To clarify, with 36 items drawn from the very large set I'd ideally like 12 red, 12 green, 12 blue, 12 triangles, 18 small etc.

Now there are 18 possible distinct item types (3 colours * 3 shapes * 2 sizes) so one way of doing this would be to include two of each distinct type (assuming that I have them).

If I *don't* have sufficient of each distinct type, another (impractical, brute force) approach, would be to iterate over every possible subset of 36 items and keep the best subset.

I'm sure that this is a specific instance of a broader class of problems solvable by a well known algorithm but I can't determine the magic words for Google. I've tagged as `knapsack-problem` because it feels like perhaps it's this but I wonder if there's a better way to solve this?

Can you help with either a solution or at least appropriate search terms?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536902/how-can-i-reward-diversity-in-an-objective-function-in-integer-programming

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115135/algorithm-to-split-people-into-groups-with-most-diversity-per-group which was closed because it did not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. I think your question will have answers on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Define "as diverse as possible" properly. I understand that ideally you want 12 red, 12 green, 12 blue, 12 triangles, 18 small, 18 large. But what if you can't do it? What is the next best? How do we compare two different selections to determine which one is better? Try to come up with a formula that assigns a numeric score to a selection, so that we can think about an algorithm that maximizes that score.

Comment: Voting to reopen because this question is asking for a software algorithm, which per the Tour is on topic for SO.

Comment: @yemre No individual attribute carries more weight than any other. I think if we represent the answer as a vector with 8 elements (3 shapes + 3 colours + 2 sizes) then the 'correct' answer would be [12,12,12,12,12,12,18]T (or we could use fractions: [ 1/3, 1/3, ...]T Then a simple Manhattan distance between an actual answer and the correct answer would be sufficient. Obv. the distance will be even because an extra triangle means one less other shape but this doesn't affect an optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). Make one reservoir for each shape/color/size combination (so 36 reservoirs), each reservoir having capacity 36. Do one pass over all your elements, and for each element select its appropriate reservoir and perform the reservoir sampling step.

This reduces your problem to at most 36*36 = 1296 elements, fairly sampled from all of them, and covers even the worst case where there is only a single combination.

Then you can simply shuffle the reservoirs, pick a random element from each (skipping empty reservoirs), removing them from the reservoirs. If you had one of each shape/color/size, you are immediately done.  If not, you shuffle the reservoirs again and do another pass, and keep doing this until you have selected 36 elements. This gives you a uniform sample over your dataset, normalized by shape/color/size biases.